# ASTVisitor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I am learning how to do an ASTVisitor for a project, so I started using Eclipse, which has a comprehensive API for that.

I have downloaded the Packed Example Project from this website:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html

But I realised that the codes do not have a main() method, yet I am able to run the program! Anyone knows why? [qn 1]

However the codes seems too compilated to work with, and the instructions for doing something basic are not very clear.

So I also went on to look at this:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Anyone knows how can I write a main method to invoke execute(ExecutionEvent event)? -- provide a sample code snippet? [qn 2]
I don't know how do use ExecutionEvent...

I kept getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed." even if I remove the parameter for Execution Event (also need to remove the extends part) or use part of the code in my main. It seems that it has to do with "ResourcesPlugin" in `IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()`. Anyone knows why? [qn 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not confident enough to categorically say you need to be writing a plugin to use the ASTVisitor, but it is the easiest way. Find some simple plugin code that creates a button or something you can press and start the run of your code. There is a sample plugin in the Plugin Development Environment that does just this (download the appropriate version of Eclipse if you do not have this).

**Creating a plugin project:**

To create a plugin project got to your package explorer and right click or open the file menu. Select the top item "new..." this opens a submenu where you selct "other...".
The "new" dialog is opened. Open the folder "plug-in development" and select "plug-in project".

[image]

Click next a few times, input the necessary information until you reach the following page:

[image]

Here the first sample "Hello World" creates a menu in your 2nd level eclipse. Run the 2nd level eclipse by going to the plugin.xml of the new project, go to the tab overview.

You'll see a page like this:

[image]

click "launch an eclipse application", and another eclipse will be started with your new plugin up and running. Click the sample action button in this 2nd level eclipse to see some sweet action.

Now you can go ahead and replace the action code with whatever you want. In this case creating and starting a visit operation.

**To create an ASTVisitor:**

Create a class that extends ASTVisitor so you can add your own code.

- preVisit(ASTNode) does a preorder traversal of the AST
- postVisit(ASTNode) does a postorder traversal of the AST
- visit(...) inspects a specific node

Add something like this to your visitor:

```
private void startVisit(IFile file) {
    ICompilationUnit icu = JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom(file);

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setSource(icu);

    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    cu.accept(this);
}
```

Now add code to your button press action that creates your visitor and calls this function:

```
MyVisitor mv = new MyVisitor();
mv.startVisit(...);
```

**To get an IFile** *(here you'll need to be a plug-in or you'll get the error you have reported)* **:**

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(...).getFile(...);
```

Replace the appropriate project and file names (strings) for the ellipsis.

Now every time you press the button the file gets visited, and the code you entered will be executed at the appropriate times (it is very insightfull to just print out every ASTNode in pre or postvisit).

Comment: But how do I create an IFile? I still need "IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();" right? But doing that will get me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed."  
Do I need to create a plugin project in eclipse to do that? Cos currently I am using main to run. How do I create a plugin project?

Answer (score 1):

Your project should be an Eclipse plug-in project, not a simple Java project with a main() method.

Here's a suggestion: take a look at the [AST View](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) tool. It's a tool designed to inspect the AST. Work with the source, run it, debug it, put breakpoints, modify the code, see how it works.

Also, make sure you have all the JDT sources. There are many examples of ASTVisitors (just make sure not to use any internal methods).

Comment: I know this is years later, but I was having a difficult time finding the right nodes to visit for a custom Java validator (think "using a custom framework correctly"). I had spent hours trying of trial and error with the debugger trying to find the right nodes to visit and what to do with this. This plugin made it so I could do the same thing in an Eclipse view and spend a fraction of the time. Thank you very much for pointing this out.